# Debugging minified JavaScript in Visual Studio with sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, minify, source-maps

We have an ASP.NET 3.5 (IIS Application Pool 2.0) webSite.
We are developing it with **Visual Studio 2013** update4 in **Windows8.1**.
The problem is that: When I minify JavaScript files (with **Web Essentials** extension) and change the aspx files to use the newly created *min.js* files, the debugger of **Visual Studio** or any other browser wont works correctly.
We expected that we work on the original *js* file (put a breakpoint etc. . .), and web browser runs it's minified *min.js* file (since relations exist in the *map* file), but in Visual Studio my break points turns into hollow yellow circle (with Tooltip: *The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No Symbols have been . . .*) even after I refresh the page with hitting Ctrl+F5 and when debugging in **Chrome** many weird problems happens like: variable's value cannot be read, break point do not hits in right place and . . .
What I try so far is cleaning, rebuilding the web project in Visual Studio, reset the Internet Explorer and Chrome settings and updating Visual Studio and Web Essentials extension and minify the JavaScript Files again with new version.

Comment: The simple answer to this is don't use minified JavaScript files when you are developing.  Same them for production.

Answer (score 1):

Building further on this answer to another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117035/19594

A simple sourcemaps file looks something like this:

```
{
    version : 3,
    file : "someFile.js",
    sourceRoot : "/",
    sources : ["some/relative/path/someFile.ts"],
    names : ["bla", "bla", "bla"],
    mappings: "aaaG,agAA,agGG,acAA"
}
```

If the values for `sources` or `sourceRoot` are relative paths (as in the above example), Visual Studio won't know what source files to connect to.

You need to set either `sources` or `sourceRoot` to point to an absolute path. You can probably do this in one of  several ways:

Either manualy edit the .js.map file to reflect an absolute path. Like this:

```
{
    version : 3,
    file : "someFile.js",
    sourceRoot : "c:\my-absolute-root-path/",
    sources : ["some/relative/path/someFile.ts"],
    names : ["bla", "bla", "bla"],
    mappings: "aaaG,agAA,agGG,acAA"
}
```

Or set up you sourcemap generator to emit the full path. I used `gulp` and `gulp-sourcemaps` like this:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

var srcFiles = ["**/*.js"];
var distPath = "dist/";

gulp.task("default", function () {
    return gulp.src(jsSrcFiles)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat("app.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename("app.min.js"))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(".", { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: "C:\my-absolute-root-path" }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath));
});
```

Comment: Thank you , for answer. I don`t use minified JavaScript any more.